# Salesforce apex code creates duplicates in custom object

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have this apex batch class:
The MDU_Squad_Data_min__c custom object below has a lot of duplicate values in the city & province column. 
With the below code I was able to get rid of duplicates with the help of the contains method to a certain extent, but still there are duplicate values:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<MDU_Squad_Data_min__c> cities) {                  
        List<sumchans__City_Master__c> cityList = new List<sumchans__City_Master__c>(); 
        List<String> cityProvinceList = new List<String>();
        for(MDU_Squad_Data_min__c c: cities) { 
            String cityprovince; 
            cityprovince = (c.CITY_NAME__c).trim() + (c.PROVINCE_CODE__c).trim();                                           
            if(!cityProvinceList.contains(cityprovince)) { 

                sumchans__City_Master__c city = new sumchans__City_Master__c();
                city.Name = c.CITY_NAME__c;
                city.sumchans__PROVINCE__c = c.PROVINCE_CODE__c; 
                cityList.add(city);
            }
            cityProvinceList.add(cityprovince);
        }        
        Database.SaveResult[] MySaveResult = Database.Insert(cityList, false);
```

Also attaching the results:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all what was needed. I am getting the expected the results now. I just had to put the second argument with a higher value than the total number of records.

```
cityMduMaster c = new cityMduMaster();
database.executeBatch(c,5000000);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest below, as List.contains mainly used for String search.
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List cities) {
    List cityList = new List();
    List cityProvinceList = new List();
    for(MDU_Squad_Data_min__c c: cities)
    {
        String cityprovince;
        cityprovince = TRIM(c.CITY_NAME__c) + TRIM(c.PROVINCE_CODE__c);

```
    if(!cityProvinceList.contains(cityprovince)) { 

        sumchans__City_Master__c city = new sumchans__City_Master__c();
        city.Name = c.CITY_NAME__c;
        city.sumchans__PROVINCE__c = c.PROVINCE_CODE__c; 
        cityList.add(city);
                                                  }
   cityProvinceList.add(cityprovince); 
}
Database.SaveResult[] MySaveResult = Database.Insert(cityList, false);
```

}

Comment: Pundarrekam is suggesting the same thing I was above.  You need to store a unique value somewhere to compare.  Don't compare the objects, you need to compare a string value like Pundarrekam and I suggested.

Comment: Hello @Pundareekam, I tried the exact same code you provided, it didn't work for me.

Comment: @Pundareekam, I got my original post edited as well, with the code you gave me. It doesn't show any errors, But it is the same output as before.

Comment: I tried with limited amount of data, with just 2 cities, still I got duplicates, but when I cut it down to an even shorter list, I was able to get rid of the duplicates. Could it be something with the data?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a set instead of a list:

```
Set<sumchans__City_Master__c> cityList = new Set<sumchans__City_Master__c>();
```

Sets are used to create unique collections so you won't have any duplicates.

Comment: Thanks @BlakeReimer. That didn't help, it is still the same result as above.

Comment: This is what I found out so far. I tried creating 4 custom objects each having a single city with its dupes. City A had 121 records which came out as 1 when I ran the above code, City B had 170 records which also came out as 1. City C had 222 records but came out as 2 and City D had 406 records but it came out as 3. I wondering if this has anything to do with the batch processing. I have heard when we create a batch class it will process the data in 200's and if the variables are getting re-initialized after the first batch of 200 records.

Comment: Also when I did Sytem.debug(cities.size()), it gave me only 200, which was supposed to 292.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a list.contains using an object and since you are creating new objects each time they aren't being found as a match.

```
 global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<MDU_Squad_Data_min__c> cities) {  
List<sumchans__City_Master__c> cityList = new List<sumchans__City_Master__c>();  
Set<String> cityNames = new Set<String>();     
for(MDU_Squad_Data_min__c c: cities)
{
   if(!cityNames.contains(c.City_Name__c))
   {
     sumchans__City_Master__c city = new sumchans__City_Master__c();
     city.Name = c.CITY_NAME__c;
     city.sumchans__PROVINCE__c = c.PROVINCE_CODE__c; 
     cityList.add(city);
     cityNames.add(city.CITY_NAME__c); 
   }
}
Database.SaveResult[] MySaveResult = Database.Insert(cityList, false);
```

}

Comment: Thanks @Psymn. That didn't work, its the same result set I am getting like before.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the quick fix, as pointed out by you, that on giving a higher value of the argument than the total number of records, the desired results are achieved.

Comment: I have no idea of any other ways we could make this work. Also nobody here came up with an answer as well.